# vim re-enter insert mode on CmdWinLeave

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map the `<C-q>` combination to enter/exit the Command Line Window (CmdWin).

But when I leave the CmdWin, I'm not able to return to the `insert` mode, but vim automatically goes back to the `normal` mode

In my `.vimrc` the following snippet is used, but doesn't work.

```
nmap <C-q> <Esc>:<C-f>
imap <C-q> <Esc><C-q>
au CmdWinLeave * startinsert!
```

I've also tried with:

```
au CmdWinLeave * startinsert
au CmdWinLeave * normal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map: `imap <C-q> <Esc>:q<CR>a`, then it will re-enter insert mode when you press `<C-q>` when you are editing in CmdWin.